# NFC запуск 2-х разных activity

Tags: java, android, nfc

есть приложение с 2 activity (Morning и Evening) и 2 метки. Как запускать при контакте с каждой меткой свою activity? Пробую через добавление intent-filter в манифест. Делаю вот так 
    `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vkr.ksenija_i.IN_OUT"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bez2"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MorningActivity"
            android:label="Вход"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.vkr.ksenija_i.IN_OUT.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EveningActivity"
            android:label="Выход"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">



            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.vkr.ksenija_i.IN_OUT.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WhoActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Представиться">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.vkr.ksenija_i.IN_OUT.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AdminActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Панель администратора">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.vkr.ksenija_i.IN_OUT.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

но какой фильтр нужен для запуска другой activity?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил создать третью "невидимую" активити без UI и с `noHistory` и только для неё оставить экшн `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`. В этой третьей активити в `onCreate` читать NFC метку и в зависимости от результата стартовать `MorningActivity` или `EveningActivity`.

На англоязычном stackoverflow есть [такой же вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996397/multiple-activities-with-ndef-discovered), где один из ответов предлагает воспользоваться моим способом, а второй отсылает к [Foreground Dispatch System](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch)

Comment: тоже рассматривала такой способ, показалось, что сразу вызывать нужную активити проще. Сейчас уже так не кажется)

Comment: может подскажете, какой триггер лучше сделать? В метку просто записать текст и потом сравнивать в  свитч-кейс? или для NFC есть способ лучше?

Comment: Никогда толком не работал с NFC, но думаю, что подход именно такой: записывать некий ключ в метку, в приложении его считывать и в зависимости от ключа что-то делать. Обычно это через свитч-кейсы и делается.

Comment: Если всё, что вы делаете -- это запускаете разные активити, то вы можете создать словарь `HashMap<String, Class>` куда сложить `.class` ваших активитей. Считываете метку, достаёте из хэшмэпа класс и отдаёте его в `Intent` для `startActivity`. Если такого ключа в словаре нет, показываете активити с ошибкой. Но тут всё зависит от общей логики приложения, если нужно будет не всегда запускать следующую активити, то такой метод не подойдёт (ну или хранить что-то типа `HashMap<String, Runnable>`, но свитч-кейс смотрится очевиднее).